# Deserialize XML array in vb.net

Tags: xml, vb.net, xml-deserialization

I need to deserialize a XML file in VB.NET.

I'm using the standard XML library.
I'm not able to write down the vb code to define the following structure:

```
<myvar>
    <var>...</var>
    <troublecodes>
        <troublecode>
        ...
        </troublecode>
        <troublecode>
        ....
        </troublecode>
        <statusbyte>
        ....
        </statusbyte>
        <statusbyte>
        ....
        </statusbyte>
        <statusbyte>
        ....
        </statusbyte>
    </troublecodes>
</myvar>
```

My definitions are:

```
Public Class MyVar
  <XmlElement("var")> Public name As String
  <XmlElement("troublecodes")> Public troubleCodes As TroubleCodes
End Class

Public Class TroubleCodes
<XmlArrayItem("troublecode")> Public troubleCode() As TroubleCode
<XmlArrayItem("statusbyte")> Public statusByte() As StatusByte
End Class

Public Class TroubleCode
  <XmlElement("one")> Public one As String
  <XmlElement("two")> Public two As String
End Class

Public Class StatusByte
  <XmlElement("three")> Public threeAs String
  <XmlElement("four")> Public four As String
End Class
```

but the objects are not populated by the deserialization.
How can i define them?

Comment: I changed XmlArrayItem to XmlArray but again no data.

Comment: Perhaps this'll help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20133287/3740093

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problems in deserialization can typically be diagnosed by serializing an example of your root type and comparing the generated XML with the desired XML.  If I do so with your `MyVar` type (demo [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qZaw2t)) I get the following result:

```
<MyVar>
  <var>my name</var>
  <troublecodes>
    <troubleCode>
      <troublecode>
        <one>one</one>
        <two>two</two>
      </troublecode>
    </troubleCode>
    <statusByte>
      <statusbyte>
        <three>three</three>
        <four>four</four>
      </statusbyte>
    </statusByte>
  </troublecodes>
</MyVar>
```

This has the following problems:

- The root node is incorrectly capitalized.

  This can be fixed by adding [`<XmlRoot("myvar")>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlrootattribute.aspx) to your root type.
- There is an extra level of nesting of `<troubleCode>`.

  By default, `XmlSerializer` serializes all collections including arrays with an outer container element.  To suppress the outer container element and serialize the collection as a flat sequence of elements, replace the `XmlArrayItem` attribute with [`<XmlElement("troublecode")>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.aspx).
- There is also an extra level of nesting of `<statusByte>`.

Thus your types should be as follows:

```
<XmlRoot("myvar")> _
Public Class MyVar
    <XmlElement("var")> Public name As String
    <XmlElement("troublecodes")> Public troubleCodes As TroubleCodes
End Class

Public Class TroubleCodes
    <XmlElement("troublecode")> Public troubleCode() As TroubleCode
    <XmlElement("statusbyte")> Public statusByte() As StatusByte
End Class

Public Class TroubleCode
    <XmlElement("one")> Public one As String
    <XmlElement("two")> Public two As String
End Class

Public Class StatusByte
    <XmlElement("three")> Public three As String
    <XmlElement("four")> Public four As String
End Class
```

Fixed [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bB3Jzu).

Comment: @SteMMo - I copied your classes verbatim into the fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/qZaw2t, and saw the extra levels.  Have you changed the classes after asking the question?  And do the classes in the answer generate the XML you require?

Answer (score 1):

My solution is:

```
Public Class TroubleCodes  
    <XmlElement("troublecode")> Public troubleCode() As TroubleCode
    <XmlElement("statusbyte")> Public statusByte() As StatusByte
End Class
```

Serializing the variable I obtain the same XML code.