# Creating a class from nested unstructured data

Tags: c#

Is there a way to create a class for this kind of data?

```
<Condition>
    <Action/>
    <Action/>
    <Condition>
        <Action/>
        <Action/>
        <Condition>
            <Condition>
                <Action/>
            </Condition>
        </Condition>
    </Condition>
</Condition>
```

The data above is intrepreted as `<Condition>` as a `Condition Object` and `<Action>` as `Action Object`.

The Scenario is that the hierarchy could be till 1 .. n depth, and it could be n number of nested condition with n number of actions inside.

Comment: List with [mixed types](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20133007/1997232) ? Is it allowed to have multiple conditions inside one condition?

Comment: Since the data has a form of tree, why not create a `Tree<T>` class?

Comment: @Sinatr Thanks for showing your interest in the question. But this is not a XML this is just a way I wanted to show how my data would be nested.

Comment: @Dmitry I think what you are saying looks promising. Can u give me a link or something which could help me understand it well.

Comment: For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66893/tree-data-structure-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

> this is not a XML this is just a way I wanted to show how my data would be nested

Then just define 2 properties:

```
class Condition
{
    public Condition Condition {get; set;} // different name?
    public List<Action> Actions {get; set;} 
}
```

> how would i know which action is under what condition

You can enumerate nested structure to find it or just add parent information to each action:

```
class Action
{
    public Condition Parent { get; }
    public Action(Condition parent)
    {
        Parent = parent;
        parent.Actions.Add(this); // not sure if its a good idea
    }
}
```

Comment: Then how would i know which action is under what condition.

Comment: See edit. That's another question, but I also often have the same problem to put all requirements into the question. Though your comments may trigger someone else's proper answer ;)